# Not able to get value from json using jq when I replace one of the elements with variable

Tags: bash, jq

Using jq if I try to get the value of an element using string I am able to get the value. But to make it flexible if I replace it with a variable then it throws error.

```
data=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "my_db_instance_class": {
      "sensitive": false,
      "type": "string",
      "value": "db.t3.medium"
    },
    "my_db_instance_test": {
      "sensitive": false,
      "type": "string",
      "value": "db.t4.medium"
    }
}
EOF
)

#echo $data
keys=$(echo $data | jq -r '. |=keys' | jq '.[]')

#echo $keys

for key in $keys
do
  value=$(echo $data | jq --arg k "$key" '.my_db_instance_class.value')
  final_value="${final_value}${key}: ${value}"
done
```

The above code works but it not very static. Below I have replaced my_db_instance_class with a variable

```
for key in $keys
do
  value=$(echo $data | jq --arg k "$key" '.$k.value')
  final_value="${final_value}${key}: ${value}"
done
```

Error message

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$k.value 
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$k.value
jq: 2 compile errors
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$k.value 
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$k.value
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Expected final output of the whole script

> "my_db_instance_class": "db.t3.medium""my_db_instance_test":
> "db.t3.medium"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're first trying to get all the `keys`, then loop over then to show the `key` with the relevant `value`.

---

We can simplify this using just [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) like so:

```
to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.value)"
```

This will produce the following output:

```json
my_db_instance_class: db.t3.medium
my_db_instance_test: db.t4.medium
```

---

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y8ZG-bxNBO)

---

- `to_entires` [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example27)
- String interpolation (`\()`) [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example69)

Comment: Alternative: `keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k): \(.[$k].value)"`